How to use internal IP for deploying application?
I've been working with MQTTnet recently and I'm having some issues while I try to create a broker and connect to it with a client using another IP which is not the default one, which tends to be the 0.0.0.0.
For this case, lets assume that my local IP is the 192.168.1.56 and I want to have the broker at 192.168.1.57.
The broker creation and run turns to be successfully but once I try to connect to it, the connection is actively refused.
I already have add the firewall rule to allow apps listeners at port 1883 (which is the used by MQTT).
As you may see, I'm a complete noob in terms of networks, so any help would be grateful.
Here is the code example that I made:
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Server;


var mqttServerOptions = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
           .WithDefaultEndpointBoundIPAddress(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.57"))
           .WithDefaultEndpointPort(1883)
           .Build();
var server = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttServer(mqttServerOptions);
server.StartedAsync += async (e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("MQTT server started.");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
};
await server.StartAsync();

var factory = new MqttFactory();
var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();

var mqttClientOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
    .WithClientId("Client1")
    .WithTcpServer("192.168.1.57", 1883)
    .Build();

mqttClient.ConnectedAsync += async e =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to MQTT broker.");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
};

mqttClient.DisconnectedAsync += async e =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from MQTT broker.");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
};

await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(mqttClientOptions);

I also tried to perform a ping into the broker but something seems out, since the prompt says that is unreachable:
Ping result

If ping returns "host unreachable" (or similar) then it sounds like a networking issue. How did you set the ip (just putting it in the broker config is not enough, the ip must be attached to an interface in the os settings). 0.0.0.0 really just means all IPs on this host.

You can only have one connection with the same 3 properties 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port.  So client and server have to use a different IP.  Normally the Server listens on the 127.0.0.1 (loopback IP address) and client connects to the IP address of machine 192.168.1.57.

@jdweng if the server listens on 127.0.0.1 then external clients will not be able to connect to it? Also see this.

@Brits :Wrong!  That is exactly what the loopback address is for.  Remote units being able to ping the loopback and get a response.  The loopback is internally link to all IP address on the machine.

@jdweng but If I wanted to put the server on a specific local IP? Do I need to attach that IP into OS setting as @Brits said? From my understanding, I thought that starting from a base IP you can use all IP's that are inside range.
I already tested setting server on 127.0.01 and connect client to 192.168.1.57. And I receive a timeout.Connection denied if clients connects to 192.168.1.56 which is the machine one.

Range of IP depends on OS, and Network card installed.  Linux has a range of address for each machine.  Windows has on one IP for a machine.  The Windows Network card have options for range of IP.

@jdweng and this is the reason why I can't access those IPs?
The only way that I can make work the broker and the client, is to set the broker at 0.0.0.0 and the client connects to 127.0.0.1.
My Ethernet network settings are set to Obtain IP address automatically.

Test that machine is configured properly by using PING with address 192.168.1.56.  You first have to be able to PING before getting code to work with 192.168.1.56.  Once PING works that you should be able to set server to 127.0.0.1 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=net-8.0) and then have client connect to 192.168.1.56.

@jdweng I can do a ping to the 56 IP without issues.
I can set the server on 127, but when I try to connect the client to 192.168.1.56, I get a No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Normally that error occurs when the client uses 127.0.0.1.  Are you on Windows or Linux? I suspect you are on Windows and when you added port 192.168.1.56 you actually created a forwarding port that is making a connection  from 192.168.1.56 to 127.0.0.1.  Best way of checking is from cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give all the connections. Try before you start.  Then start server and repeat.

@jdweng Yes, srry, I'm on Windows10.
The only way to make appear as a connection using netstat -a is using the following code:
var mqttServerOptions = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder().WithDefaultEndpoint().Build();.
That makes to appear on that list as [::]:1883 wich I assume that is the same as 0.0.0.0:1883.
Any other IP set provokes client timeout connection or connection refused by target machine.

@jdweng disagree. @aurentium as you are using DHCP you will need to see this ref adding a second IP. Once a second address is added you will be able to listen on that address (just requests to that address) or 0.0.0.0 (requests sent to any IP the machines NIC's have been configured for).

@Brits : The link says to add a static IP to your interface.  It is not exactly the same as adding an IP to the machine like in Linux.    Do not remember if there are any functional differences between Linux implementation and Windows.  Linux everything is in one file.  Windows you have to use Netstat to add interface.

@jdweng sorry, I'm having difficulty understanding your comments. OP said they are using Windows 10 and their current IP is assigned using DHCP, so the answer I linked is specific to their situation (dhcpstaticipcoexistence needs to be set when the existing address is assigned via DHCP, otherwise Windows ignores additional IP's); they could also disable DHCP and manually set two IP's using the GUI (or netsh). In order to listen on a different IP (the original question here) they will need to 1. Add the IP to an interface 2. Listen using that IP (or 0.0.0.0).

@Brits : This has nothing to do with DHCP.  It has to do with how the loopback is implemented on windows.   When Net stat adds an interface it is not forwarding the messages to the Loopback IP 127.0.0.1.  Loopback is being implemented at the Network Card and receive messages are forwarded to the default IP 0.0.0.0.  The machine IP works different than the Netstat IP.   The machine IP gets seen by 127.0.0.1 while the Netstat IP does not get seen by 127.0.0.1.  So OP has to listen at the Default IP (0.0.0.0).  I think it is a bug in MQTTnet but not sure.

@jdweng sorry, also confusing (this will be my last response). Here is a test for you; run (new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener('192.168.1.56', 10001)).Start() (sub your IP); it will work (and the listener will visible in netstat -an). Now change the IP, it will fail (but if you add the IP to your NIC it will succeed). This is basically what I believe is happening in mqttnet when OP changes the IP.

@Brits : Op already has solution.  OP cannot use TcpListener('192.168.1.56' because it will not work.  You can't have two connections with same source and destination IP.  When you create a socket it creates a virtual connection with two source and destination IP.  The virtual connection is using either 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 as one of the endpoints which is causing issue.  It looks like Net uses 0.0.0.0 as an endpoint while MQTT is using 127.0.0.1 as the endpoint.  So what normally works with Net fails with MQTT.  The OP solution is the correct solution.

There are a few factors involved here; the first is that your server code (as per the question) does not actually listen for connections because it's missing  .WithDefaultEndpoint(). If I fix this, your code works for me (using my machines IP for both the client and server). I suspect you have another broker running on your machine (which is why your code is seemingly working when you attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1). Note that I'm using port 10,000 (to avoid any chance of that!).
If I change the IP to one that's not configured on my machine then I get the error:
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10049): The requested address is not valid in its context.

This is expected because you cannot listen on an address that's not attached to an interface on your machine. If I now add the address (see this answer for some required setup):
netsh interface ipv4 add address "interface name" 192.168.1.57 255.255.255.0

(replace interface name with the name of one of your interfaces; in my case it was "Ethernet 2").
Following this change the application works. Note that you should probably remove the address when you are done (your DHCP server may well allocate it to another machine!).
netsh interface ipv4 del address "interface name" 192.168.1.57 255.255.255.0

Please see the full code I used below (I added some logging so you can see the connection coming in):
using System.Text;
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Server;
using MQTTnet.Diagnostics;


var mqttServerOptions = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
.WithDefaultEndpointBoundIPAddress(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.57"))
.WithDefaultEndpointPort(10000)
.WithDefaultEndpoint()
.Build();
var mqttEventLogger = new MqttNetEventLogger("MyCustomLogger");
mqttEventLogger.LogMessagePublished += (sender, args) =>
       {
           var output = new StringBuilder();
           output.AppendLine($">> [{args.LogMessage.Timestamp:O}] [{args.LogMessage.ThreadId}] [{args.LogMessage.Source}] [{args.LogMessage.Level}]: {args.LogMessage.Message}");
           if (args.LogMessage.Exception != null)
           {
               output.AppendLine(args.LogMessage.Exception.ToString());
           }
           Console.Write(output);
       };
var server = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttServer(mqttServerOptions, mqttEventLogger);
server.StartedAsync += async (e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("MQTT server started.");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
};
server.ClientConnectedAsync += async (ClientConnectedEventArgs eventArgs) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Client '{eventArgs.ClientId}' connected.");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
};
server.ValidatingConnectionAsync += async (ValidatingConnectionEventArgs eventArgs) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Client '{eventArgs.ClientId}' connected.");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
};
await server.StartAsync();


var factory = new MqttFactory();
var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();

var mqttClientOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
.WithClientId("Client1")
.WithTcpServer("192.168.1.57", 10000)
.Build();

mqttClient.ConnectedAsync += async e =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to MQTT broker.");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
};

mqttClient.DisconnectedAsync += async e =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from MQTT broker.");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
};

await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(mqttClientOptions);

output:
>> [2024-06-30T05:51:25.3928051Z] [4] [MqttServerKeepAliveMonitor] [Info]: Starting keep alive monitor
>> [2024-06-30T05:51:25.3960953Z] [1] [MqttTcpServerListener] [Info]: Starting TCP listener (Endpoint=192.168.1.57:10000, TLS=False)
>> [2024-06-30T05:51:25.4057550Z] [1] [MqttTcpServerListener] [Verbose]: TCP listener started (Endpoint=192.168.1.57:10000)
>> [2024-06-30T05:51:25.4097879Z] [1] [MqttTcpServerListener] [Info]: Starting TCP listener (Endpoint=[::]:10000, TLS=False)
>> [2024-06-30T05:51:25.4102620Z] [1] [MqttTcpServerListener] [Verbose]: TCP listener started (Endpoint=[::]:10000)
MQTT server started.
>> [2024-06-30T05:51:25.4121238Z] [1] [MqttServer] [Info]: Started
>> [2024-06-30T05:51:25.4246244Z] [13] [MqttTcpServerListener] [Verbose]: TCP client '192.168.1.57:57580' accepted (Local endpoint=192.168.1.57:10000)
>> [2024-06-30T05:51:25.4312003Z] [13] [MqttChannelAdapter] [Verbose]: RX (21 bytes) <<< Connect: [ClientId=Client1] [Username=] [Password=] [KeepAlivePeriod=15] [CleanSession=True]
Client 'Client1' connected.
>> [2024-06-30T05:51:25.4333380Z] [13] [MqttClientSessionsManager] [Verbose]: Created new session for client 'Client1'
>> [2024-06-30T05:51:25.4364599Z] [13] [MqttChannelAdapter] [Verbose]: TX (4 bytes) >>> ConnAck: [ReturnCode=ConnectionAccepted] [ReasonCode=Success] [IsSessionPresent=False]
Client 'Client1' connected.
>> [2024-06-30T05:51:25.4379708Z] [13] [MqttClient] [Info]: Client 'Client1': Session started
Connected to MQTT broker.

